# css - show element then animate it (trigger by jquery addClass)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i'm trying to animate an element with css. 
First this element is hidden. A javascript event will show it and i want it to be animated.
The expected animation is letter-spacing -2px to letter-spacing 3px

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').addClass('animate');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    display: none;
    /* I dont want the wrapper to be visible before the event */
}
#wrapper .message {
    display: none; /* the message is not visible before the event */
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    transition: all 3s;
}
#wrapper.animate .message {
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
#wrapper.animate {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
        <div class="text-center font-size-20">
            <span class="message">
                Message to show and animate
            </span>
        </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click me to animate</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the real issue: 
When using a unique class to show AND change the property to animate, the browser will directly show the element with the new property (letter-spacing 3px).
To make it work, I can add a timeout.
I'm still waiting for a better solution if it exists

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').addClass('show');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       $('.message').addClass('animate');
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    display: none;
    /* I dont want the wrapper to be visible before the event */
}
#wrapper .message {
    display: none; /* the message is not visible before the event */
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    transition: all 3s;
}
#wrapper.show .message {
    display: block;
}
#wrapper .message.animate {
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
#wrapper.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
        <div class="text-center font-size-20">
            <span class="message">
                Message to show and animate
            </span>
        </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click me to animate</button>
```

Comment: Well I guess there are several ways of solving this issue you had, I rather prefer using keyframes, so that you can assign which "animation" css property you want to the class itself. So instead of using transitions which are considered slower than animation, you can have more flexibility also when you want the animation to end, or if you want to change a value in the middle of the animation, a bit more on that: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the css value of `display` instead of add a class ?

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').css('display', 'block);
});
```

And look at this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

`visibility` property can help you.

Comment: I tried with visibility and it didn't work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5h1dgfpu/

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').addClass('animate');
});
```

```css
#wrapper .message {
    display: block; /* the message is not visible before the event */
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
#wrapper.animate .message {
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
        <div class="text-center font-size-20">
            <span class="message">
                Message to show and animate
            </span>
        </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click me to animate</button>
```

Comment: The aim of the animation is not to show, it's to increase line spacing. Sorry it was not clear enough

Comment: Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5h1dgfpu/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can move the item using margin in the css, and for delay, you can use setTimeOut function in javascript, like below

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
        <div class="text-center font-size-20">
            <span class="message">
                Message to show and animate
            </span>
        </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click me to animate</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper .message {
    display: none; /* the message is not visible before the event */
    transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
    margin-left:0px;
}
#wrapper.animate .message {
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-left:30px;
}
```

**JAVA-SCRIPT**

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper span').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#wrapper').addClass('animate');
        }, 1000);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efto3e84/1/) for you

Comment: Thanks for you answe but i finally found a better solution using letter-spacing (look at my answer)

Comment: Great! and please do accept answer which helped you out the most.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer for the moment, I have to wait 2 days

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#click").click(function(){
$("#text").css("visibility","visible");
$("#text").animate({
            opacity: '1'
        });
   

});
  });
```

```css
#text{
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 25px;
   display: block;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0.2;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
 <p id="text"> Message to show and animate</p>
 </div>
 <button id="click">Click &  Animate</button>
```